# function discriminated in typescript

Tags: typescript, overloading, discriminated-union

```
const enum Tag {
  Friday = 'Friday',
  Planning = 'Planing',
}
const test = (tag: Tag, todo:/* ??? */): string => {/* some logic */}
```

when `tag` is `Tag.Friday`, `todo` should be `(tour: string) => string`

when `tag` is `Tag.Planning`, `todo` should be `(date: Date) => string`

I tried function discriminated union and function overloads, Both of which can't infer `todo` type. The [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.0-beta#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgFQIYHMYG8BQMMAYgE4CWAJhgJ4wC8MA5GVbUwDSEwAKANhjBhyYHIyb9BIrJ3wBffAHpFMKDQAOcXhlIZkARgYwAFFGwAudNgB0rajQ6qQlEJdMhEpS9AqiAlAwAfDA+0gH0waGiANxKKmqa2rrIAExGphZWWNaSQtKOUM6uJtRQcJYAIhhl4ZFQvli1IfXSscowoJCwZdCWPDp6hgA+SXppjBlYlphYBUWWgjRNBO1E5ABmJmZi9IwzthT2ASsqRESkcFCeYE4uxoAYBADCGHwbIKTCGICYBH5xZ3LwPgQLQnM7nS7XW4gYxVMrWMAgADuxj8v1WMAU7QU60QYGAUHI4FUcGgk2mNjstDmLjchU83ha-iCzQafgZDViOLxBKJPSgZKyOQEeVE1OKxlK5RgsLgTSijXZrXwXPxhJufIFizFCzASzw3A2W2wDF2gspeoIYIuVw+UOMTDQHlITF+RABcCBIO44Jt6qKMOqcHhSJRrox8iAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can use function overloading in TypeScript if you declare your function as an interface.

For example:

```
const enum Tag {
  Friday = 'Friday',
  Planning = 'Planing',
}
type TourFunc = (tour: string) => string
type DateFunc = (date: Date) => string
interface Fn {
  (tag: Tag.Friday, todo: TourFunc): string;
  (tag: Tag.Planning, todo: DateFunc): string;
}

const test: Fn = (tag: Tag, todo: TourFunc | DateFunc): string => {
  return 'a';
}

const dateFunc : DateFunc = (a: Date) => a.toDateString()
const tourFunc : TourFunc = (b: string) => b
test(Tag.Planning, (s: string) => 'a'); // Error
test(Tag.Planning, dateFunc); // Ok 
test(Tag.Friday, tourFunc); // Ok
test(Tag.Planning, tourFunc); // Error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=6&pln=5&pc=14#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgFQIYHMYG8BQMMAYgE4CWAJhgJ4wC8MA5GVbUwDSEwAKANhjBhyYHIyb9BIrJ3wBffFBoAHOOhCJSxRGGAMYACigbSALhjQKogJQMAfBahWsilWoAiGKHG279B6m9zT29begdLaXwRb1IAMwxgNWIwPG4jbHNMLAA6VmoaDhhjShAsk19ga3NI0QBudKhM9GwcySFpIpKymBCfHSqap2kGhXxQSFhvaHMU-yasLOwukFLyzUqYAB9er37dasdnezSiUjgoTVSmDCZR-HHwaBhA-b1gvc3GAwwP0JOMDljH0AMrDUQGayPSbFCoDGDrLTw74AIyGzjCDhRijg0AM2TaAg6oiKBgg6OkmOYt2sdRgOLxBPawhJL0+A1pDKg+Na+VoKw2HIa025TKJLKwAqRBwaQA)

Comment: `todo` is a function. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmArgWxgFQIYHMYG8BQMMAYgE4CWAJhgJ4wC8MA5GVbUwDSEwAKANhjBhyYHIyb9BIrJ3wBffFBoAHOOhCJSxRGGAMYACigbSALhjQKogJQMAfBahWsilWoAiGKHG279B6m9zT29begdLaXwRb1IAMwxgNWIwPG4jbHNMLAA6VmoaDhhjShAsk19ga3NI0QBudKhM9GwcySFpIpKymBCfHSqap2kGhXxQSFhvaHMU-yasLOwukFLyzUqYAB9er37dasdnezSiUjgoTVSmDCZR8fBoGED9vUYDDGC9sIcMHOM+gBlYaiAzWB6TYoVAb+ABGQ2cPxgsMUcGgBmybQEHVERTBJxuTGsdRgAHpSRYABYaPhqWFqADupHALmmUAxrXawlxzz2lWJqPRmPytBWGwGAqAA). Still not work

Comment: Actually that's expected. In your example `test(Tag.Planning, (s: string) => 'a');` will result in an error as expected. However when you don't pass any arguments to the function then the function can match both `TourFunc` and `DateFunc`. Check my update